# Make length of ROW flexible in an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The formula I have is this:

```
{=PRODUCT((1-0.1)^(ROW(A$1:A$2)-1))}
```

However, I would like to make the length of ROW dependent on a value in a cell (e.g. B1). My solution so far is this

```
{=PRODUCT((1-0.1)^(ROW(INDIRECT("A$1:A$"&B1))-1))}
```

Given that INDIRECT is volatile, I am not really satisfied with this solution. So the question is: Is there another way of solving this problem without using a volatile function?

Thanks!

Edit: Changed decimal separator from 0,1 to 0.1

Comment: `=PRODUCT(2^(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,B1))-1))` ? BTW i'm not sure what `(1-0,1)` is.

Comment: @Rosetta: `OFFSET` is also volatile.

Comment: OFFSET is also a volatile function and thus unfortunately doesn't solve the issue. The 0.1 is just a percentage (forget to change the decimal separator) which is subtracted from 1. So the whole expression will later be multiplied with something else (which I left out here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most times - not all times - `INDIRECT` solutions can be replaced with `INDEX`.

In this case:

```
{=PRODUCT((1-0.1)^(ROW(A$1:INDEX($A:$A,B1))-1))}
```

In this special case this solution is also not 100% satisfactioning because the `INDEX` will be recalculated every time a value in column `A` will be changed. This would not be necessary in this case since only the row number is needed from column `A`. But it will be better than a volatile function which will recalculated every time a value somewhere in the sheet will be changed.